# Error "not an association id" in nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, nhibernate

I got the following error message from nhibernate:

> {"not an association: ID"}

```
Model.Order orderAlias = null;
Model.Unit unitAlias = null;
```

query to reproduce:

```
var query = m_hibernateSession.QueryOver<Model.Order>(() => orderAlias)
                    .JoinAlias(() => orderAlias.ID, () => unitAlias, JoinType.InnerJoin)
                    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.PONumber).Desc.Take(5);
```

(for DB model look also here: [nhibernate criteria for selecting from different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338535/nhibernate-criteria-for-selecting-from-different-tables))

What does this mean and how can I correctly retrieve my result list?

Thx

Comment: just check that in orderAlias table of your m_hibernateSession context ID column is there or not,if not then it that table in your m_hibernateSession context again and then try..

Comment: I init this aliases with null (you see this if you follow the link)! Are other steps necessary?

Comment: if your orderAlias is null it means ID that your are fetching from orderAlias table will also be null..then how it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In Model.Order class, ID should be of type Model.Unit.

Make sure you have classes for both Model.Order and Model.Unit