# Nhibernate add filter to query

Tags: c#, sql, hibernate, sqlite, nhibernate

Reference: [nhibernate criteria for selecting from different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338535/nhibernate-criteria-for-selecting-from-different-tables)

Based on this question I want to filter this retrieved last 5 orders by at example Unit.Amount == 5! (add filter) I think it's possible with something like this:

```
var query = m_hibernateSession.QueryOver<Model.Order>()
// .Where(x => x.Units[].Amount == 5) ... // which Unit to select in this list?
.OrderBy(x => x.PONumber).Desc.Take(5);
```

Could someone please help me to find the right query?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a join should solve your problem

```
Order orderAlias = null;
Unit unitsAlias = null;
var query = session.QueryOver<Order>(() => orderAlias)
  .JoinAlias(() => orderAlias.Units, () => unitsAlias, JoinType.InnerJoin)
  .Where(() => unitsAlias.Amount == 5)
  .OrderBy(x => x.PONumber).Desc.Take(5);
```

Comment: You can just create a QeryOver<Unit>() and extract what you need

Comment: I tried it: var query = m_hibernateSession.QueryOver<Model.Unit>( () => unitsAlias )
                    .JoinAlias(() => unitsAlias.OrderRef, () => orderAlias, JoinType.InnerJoin)                      
                    .Where(() => unitsAlias.Amount == 5)  
                    .OrderBy(x => x.PONumber).Desc.Take(amount); But got error message: "could not resolve property: PONumber of: DCGOrderSystem.Model.Unit"

Comment: insetad of x=>xPONumber try () => orderAlias.PONumber