# Can't delete last item from nhibernate model (cascading issue)

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

Based on this mappings: [nhibernate criteria for selecting from different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338535/nhibernate-criteria-for-selecting-from-different-tables)

If I want to delete the last Model.Order I get this error message:

```
"deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations"
```

Here my code:

```
Model.Unit unitToDelete = m_MainGUI.Manager.RetrieveEquals<Model.Unit>("ID", unitID)[0];
Model.Order currentOrder = m_MainGUI.Manager.RetrieveEquals<Model.Order>("ID", unitToDelete.OrderRef.ID)[0];

if (currentOrder.Units.Count == 1) // last unit of order
{                    
    // delete references
    unitToDelete.OrderRef = null;
    unitToDelete.EmployeeRef = null;



    currentOrder.Units.Remove(unitToDelete); // remove unit from collection                                                       
    m_MainGUI.Manager.Delete<Model.Unit>(unitToDelete);


    m_MainGUI.Manager.Delete<Model.Order>(currentOrder); <---- ERROR
}
else
{
    currentOrder.Units.Remove(unitToDelete); // remove unit from collection
    m_MainGUI.Manager.Save<Model.Order>(currentOrder); // update order with removed unit
}
```

My delete method

```
public void Delete<T>(T item)
{
    using (m_HibernateSession.BeginTransaction())
    {
        m_HibernateSession.Delete(item);
        m_HibernateSession.Transaction.Commit();
        m_HibernateSession.Flush();
    }
}
```

Unit.cs (parts of them)

```
public virtual Employee EmployeeRef { get; set; }
    public virtual Order OrderRef { get; set; }

    public virtual string Employee
    {
        get
        {
            if (EmployeeRef != null) return EmployeeRef.Name;
            else return "";
        }
    }

    public virtual int PONumber
    {
        get
        {
            return OrderRef.PONumber;
        }
    }

    public virtual int OrderID
    {
        get
        {
            return OrderRef.ID;
        }
    }
```

Order.cs (parts of them)

```
private IList<Unit> m_UnitsList = new List<Unit>(); 

public virtual IList<Unit> Units
    {
        get { return m_UnitsList; }
        set { m_UnitsList = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Distributor
    {
        get
        {
            if (Units.Count != 0) return Units[0].Distributor;
            return "";
        }
    }

    public virtual string Department
    {
        get
        {
            if (Units.Count != 0) return Units[0].Department;
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Any hints whats wrong?

Thx

Comment: What else has a reference to Order?

Comment: `m_HibernateSession.Flush();` is redundant after a Commit which does already Flush all. Also why `m_MainGUI.Manager.RetrieveEquals<Model.Order>("ID", unitToDelete.OrderRef.ID)[0];` instead of `unitToDelete.OrderRef`?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you have reference to Order from Unit, so you need to do Unit.Order = null.